# Best way to import data from MySql to HDFS

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to know is there any way to import data from mysql to HDFS, there are some conditions I need to mention.

- I know hbase,hive and sqoop can help me , but I dont wan't any extra layers. Just mapreduce and hadoop java api.
- I also need to update HDFS as data is updated in mySQL.

I need to know best way to import mysql data into HDFS and update in real time.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you want to use sqoop - it does what you would have to do (open a JDBC connection get data , write to hadoop) see [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/hw09-sqoop-database-import-for-hadoop) from hadoop world 09

Comment: Yes sir , I know but wanted to see can just hadoop do it with some extra written code.And can sqoop also solve my problem of real time record update in hdfs as we update in mysql db?

Comment: You can take a look at scoop code and write a subset of that if you're inclined to so. regarding real-time update you need an "change-data-capture" solution for mySQL that can write to HDFS to do that (e.g. this one from talend http://www.talend.com/resource/change-data-capture.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Real Time import using CDC and Talend.
http://www.talend.com/talend-big-data-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the database and HDFS via JDBC connectors and hadoop Java  API.

But in map-reduce things will be out of your control when accessing a database.

- Each mapper/reducer tries to establish a separate connection to database, eventually impacts the database performance.
- There won't be any clue which mapper/reducer executes what portion of the query result set.
- Incase if there is a single mapper/reducer to access the database then hadoop parallelism will be lost.
- Fault tolerant mechanism has to be implemented if any of the mapper/reducer is failed.
- list goes on......

To overcome all these hurdles, Sqoop was developed to transfer data between RDBMS to/from HDFS.